# Creating Azure resource using Azure portal over SDK

Tags: azure

When I have to prefer Azure portal over SDK option while creating Azure based business solution?(provided SDK option available for the resource)
What are the pros & cons of one over another?
My question is generic one but for clarify sake, if I am going develop 'Azure Service Bus' based business solution which one to choose? when? & why? what I will lose or what I will gain? please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thats pretty clear, when you want to automate something you use automation means (scripts\sdk\templates\etc), when you want to do something one off and quickly - you use the portal (or when you are only getting familiar with something, portal is usually more trivial).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Still many of questions are remaining unanswered. Also you can automate via portal too.

Comment: well, technically you can, but its not supported and this is not something you should do, as it makes no sense. i dont see any unanswered question. your question is really general, hence the answer is general. question boils down to manual vs automated deployment. its quite obvious what are the advantages\disadvantages of both

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'automation' in this context for which we have to use scripts\sdk\templates\etc? any example will help me in understanding better.

Comment: automation is self explanatory. automation is when something happens repeatedly in a controlled fashion without manual intervention. for example, if you need to repeatedly provision a vm. you could do that using the portal, but when you actually do that for the 5th time you'd probably start wishing there is some sort of button you can press that will do that for you

Comment: To make my self clear, here is my doubt if I want to create service bus/topic/subscription which option I have to choose azure portal option or developing c# application using sdk to create service bus/topic/subscription? and why?

Comment: its really depends, both ways work. i tend to think code is always better. you dont have to use sdk though. powershell would be a lot easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191921/discussion-between-thiru-and-4c74356b41).